# Не работает async/await в map JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, map

Не могу понять почему в результирующем массиве остаются промисы

```
const ids = [1, 2]
const cards = ids.map(async(id) =>{
    const card = []
    card.id = id
    card.price = await (запрос на бд для цены)
    return(
       card
    )
})
```

Получаю такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал и перед мапом await ставить, все равно также

Comment: Собери массив промисов и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: `const cards = await Promise.all(ids.map(async(id)=>{...}))`

https://doka.guide/js/promise-all/#roman-yurlov-sovetuet

Comment: Спасибо большое, а почему это вообще так работает? Как я после await могу промис получить?

Comment: @Strygwyr, ты получаешь promise, не после await, а после map, который в твоем случае маппит элемент на Promise.

Comment: я и перед мапом пробовал ставить, даже в вопросе про это написал, все равно промисы возвращал. Попробую еще раз, может реально ошибся где то

Comment: @Strygwyr, `map` возвращает массив, с промисами, перед ним нет смысла ставить await. Именно поэтому и ты используешь `Promise.all`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо большое, не знал что мап промисы дает

Comment: @Strygwyr, он возвращает  массив, с промисами именно в твоем случае. Так как функция, которую ты передаешь - возвращает Promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо собрать массив промисов в `Promise.All`, так как map собирает массив промисов если там есть чего ожидать и await не ждет их решения

```
const cards = await Promise.all(ids.map(async(id)=>{...}))
```